# Execute Process Task - Not working in SSIS Properly

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis

I have a python code which reads a csv file, creates a table in sql and inserts records inside that table. The code works perfectly fine. The SSIS task takes around 2-3 minutes to run and its okay, because the code would require that much time, but it is not creating anything on the database.

This is my code,

```
#Import the required libraries
import pandas
import pyodbc
import os

#Set the Current Directory
path="C:/Users/MOLAP/Desktop/Data Warehouse Project/1. Datasets/Structured Data"
os.chdir(path)

#Establish connection with the server and the database
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=MOLAP;'
    r'DATABASE=EnergyUsageEffects_Database;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#If a table is present - Truncate it else create the table
if cursor.tables(table='EnergyConsumption_Electrical', tableType='TABLE').fetchone():
    cursor.execute("Truncate table EnergyConsumption_Electrical")
    cnxn.commit()
else:   
    cursor.execute("Create table EnergyConsumption_Electrical (CountryName nvarchar(255), Year nvarchar(255), Unit nvarchar(255), Indicator nvarchar(255), Product nvarchar(255), ConsumptionValue float) ")
    cnxn.commit()


#Read the CSV Inside the dataframe
df = pandas.read_csv("Electrical Energy Types.csv")

#Convert the dataframe into a list
ReqList = df.values.tolist()

#Loop through the list and Insert record after record inside the table
for i in range(len(ReqList)):
    Val1 = ReqList[i][0]
    Val2= ReqList[i][1]
    Val3= ReqList[i][2]
    Val4= ReqList[i][3]
    Val5= ReqList[i][4]
    Val6= ReqList[i][5]
    cursor.execute("insert into EnergyConsumption_Electrical (CountryName, Year, Unit, Indicator, Product, ConsumptionValue) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, Val5, Val6)
    cnxn.commit()
```

This is my configuration on the SSIS,

[image]

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: You haven't specified what isn't working with what you've posted. What is the error message? What is the behaviour that you are experiencing?

Comment: By the way, there's absolutely no reason to have written all that python code, that's native functionality of SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Remove this task from your package.

Step 2) Create a Data Flow that has a Flat File Source that points to your .csv and an OLE DB Destination task that points to your database.table.

There's really no reason to reinvent the wheel here. SSIS has native tools to make this task mostly trivial.